# removing special chars and adding a dash between words php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to strip all special chars and add a dash between all the words.

Example:

Example text:
How to make something, something else, and other stuff.

Example string:

```
$string = "How to make something, something else, and other stuff.";
```

Example of how it should look:
How-to-make-something-something-else-and-other-stuff

I need a function that will strip all special chars but also add the dashes between every word "but also not adding dashes after the last word". Anyone have any ideas of how I should do this? I assume this is fairly simple. probably a preg_replace with regex which would solve the special char problem but adding the dashes is where I get confused and am not sure what to do.

Comment: How do you define "special chars"? Non-alphanumeric characters? Or anything besides a-z?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the string is in utf-8:

```
$string = 'Höw to máke sòmething, something else, and other stuff';
$string = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/i','-',
   iconv('UTF-8','ASCII//TRANSLIT',$string));
$string = trim($string,'-');
```

Comment: The problem with that is it adds a dash after the last word. Other wise that would be fine.

Comment: Ah, OK, I'll edit it in if you don't want that... It's just the final `.` getting replaced by `-` :)

Comment: Cool seems to work great. I will accept your answer in 6 minutes when it allows me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

After you've removed the non-alpha characters, you can [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) on spaces and then [`implode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) with dashes.

Comment: That is a good idea but Wrikken's answer is more of what I was looking for. Thanks for your advice, it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would explode the string at the spaces and then implode it with dashes like this:

```
$string = trim($string); // removes white space from ends
$string = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/","",$string); // removes special chars 
$string = explode(' ', $string); // separates the words where there are spaces
$string = implode('-', $string); // puts the words back into a sentence separated by dashes
echo $string;
```

this can be condensed obviously - but for simplicity these are the steps needed.